# How do I make "TreeListControl" appear as a "TreeView"?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

VS 2017
DEVEXPRES 17.2
WPF

There is a table in MS Access

[image]

Based on the table, "TreeListControl"

[image]

How to make "TreeListControl" appear as "TreeView"

[image]

I want to say how to make sure that items that are marked with crosses are not displayed

[image]

In WinForm, this is done when you set it in the menu "ViewStyle" / "TreeView"

[image]

In WPF, I did not find this.

**Question.**
How do I make "TreeListControl" appear as a "TreeView"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish your task by hiding some TreeListControl's TreeListView visual elements:

- [column headers](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/7569/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Visual-Elements/Common-Elements/Column-Header-Panel) (the [TreeListView.ShowColumnHeaders](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataViewBase.ShowColumnHeaders.property) property)
- lines between cells (the [TreeListView.ShowHorizontalLines](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.TreeListView.ShowHorizontalLines.property) and the [TreeListView.ShowVerticalLines](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.TreeListView.ShowVerticalLines.property)  properties)
- [indicator panel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/7288/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Visual-Elements/Table-View-Elements/Row-Indicator-Panel) (the [TreeListView.ShowIndicator](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.TreeListView.ShowIndicator.property) property)

And of course, you should have the only single column visible at once (the [TreeListColumn.Visible](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.BaseColumn.Visible.property) property);

Comment: You could not help with this question.
Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585564/treelistcontrol-how-do-i-drag-a-record-between-parent-nodes